# How to fix 'paused before out-of-memory crash' contract deployment error in browser? [ConseilJS]

Tags: smart-contracts, error, javascript, conseil, deploy

I wish to deploy a contract using [ConseilJS](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/f189bc1d8aafa33db2d5beb587711faadfb51e50/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts) that I am able to originate successfully using [smartpy.io](https://smartpy.io/dev/origination.html)

However, when I copy the generated Michelson and initial storage into the following function:

```
async function deploy_contract(){
  const server='https://babylonnet.SmartPy.io'; //same as smartpy.io
  const keystore={ //working for contract invocations
    publicKey:'foo',
    privateKey:'foo',
    publicKeyHash:'foo',
    seed:'',
    storeType:conseiljs.StoreType.Fundraiser
  };
  const amount=0; //same as smartpy.io
  const delegate=undefined;
  const fee=100000; //same as smartpy.io
  const derivationPath='';
  const storageLimit=20000; //same as smartpy.io
  const gasLimit=500000; //same as smartpy.io
  const code=`
    .
    .
  `;
  const storage=`
    .
    .
  `;
  const codeFormat=conseiljs.TezosParameterFormat.Michelson;
  const result=await conseiljs.TezosNodeWriter.sendContractOriginationOperation(
   server,
   keystore,
   amount,
   delegate,
   fee,
   derivationPath,
   storageLimit,
   gasLimit,
   code,
   storage,
   codeFormat
 );
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,4));
}
```

The variables `code` and `storage` contain the Michelson and initial storage produced by SmartPy which can be deployed through an online tool. However, when I run this function the browser (in this case Chrome) produces the error `paused before out-of-memory crash` in the console.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the Micheline / JSON version created by SmartPy.io.
This is what is actually sent from SmartPy.io.

You also need to change the `conseiljs.TezosParameterFormat.Michelson` parameter into `conseiljs.TezosParameterFormat.Micheline`.

Comment: This appears to have resolved the problem! Thanks for this.